# File download but Save File dialogue not opening

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, google-chrome, extjs5

Using ASP.NET, ExtJS5, SQL Server and ClosedXML.

I'm using ExtJS to call down to a database stored procedure, and saving the results to an excel file on the server with ClosedXML.

The file is being created correctly, and looking at the network inspector, I can verify the file is being downloaded, but I am not getting any kind of `Save` dialogue. All I've found are solutions to disable that pop-up (I'd love to have that problem).

I've tried on Chrome, Firefox and IE, same story for each.

The the panel that calls the service:

```
Ext.define('Table', {
    xtype: 'file-table',
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    title: 'Stuff for Excel',
    hideHeaders: false,
    cls: 'striped-grid',
    store: 'Stuff for Excel Store',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.selection.SpreadsheetModel',
        'Ext.grid.plugin.Clipboard'
    ],
    selModel: {
        type: 'spreadsheet',
        rowSelect: false,
        columnSelect: true  
    },
    plugins: ['clipboard', 'gridfilters'],
    features: [{
        ftype: 'grouping',
        hideGroupedHeader: true,
        startCollapsed: true
    }],
    columns: [{
        text: '#1',
        dataIndex: 'Name',
        flex: 1,
        filter: {
            type: 'string',
            itemDefaults: {
                emptyText: 'Filter by...'
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: '#2',
        dataIndex: 'Type',
        flex: 1,
        hidden: true,
        filter: {
            type: 'string',
            itemDefaults: {
                emptyText: 'Filter by...'
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: '#3',
        dataIndex: 'Sub-Type',
        flex: 1,
        filter: {
            type: 'string',
            itemDefaults: {
                emptyText: 'Filter by...'
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: '#4',
        dataIndex: 'Sub-sub Type',
        flex: 1,
        filter: {
            type: 'string',
            itemDefaults: {
                emptyText: 'Filter by...'
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: '#5',
        dataIndex: 'Weight',
        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
        renderer: function (value) {
            var out = value * 100;
            return out.toFixed(1) + ' %';
        },
        flex: 0
    }],
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    },
    bbar: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        margin: 5,
        padding: 10,
        text: 'Export to Excel',
        hidden: false,
        flex: 0,
        icon: '../Images/ExportReport.png',
        handler: function () {
            Ext.Ajax.request({      
                method: 'GET',
                loadMask: true,
                url: 'ReportingWebServices.asmx/CreateExcel',
                params: {
                    'here': are,
                    'some': params
                }
            })
        }
    }]
});
```

The relevant server-side code

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public void CreateExcel()
{
    string fileName = "Workbook.xlsx";
    string filePath = "path\to\file";
    ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook workBook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook(); 

    // Passing params, getting results from database,
    // building the spreadsheet

    if (File.Exists(filePath + fileName))
    {
        File.Delete(filePath + fileName);
    }

    workBook.SaveAs(filePath + fileName);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(filePath + fileName);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Comment: We can see how you transmit the file, but not how you called it from the browser. Add the code which downloads the file, not the one which sends it as the error should be on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

@Gusman's comment helped me figure out where I could be looking. The issue was indeed in the front-end code. I added a function to my button handler that appended an invisible iframe.

```
 handler: function () {

            var fileName = 'fileName.xlsx'

            Ext.Ajax.request({      
                method: 'GET',
                loadMask: true,
                url: 'ReportingWebServices.asmx/GetExcel',
                params: {
                    'sessionId': reportingSelectedSessionGUID,
                    'userId': reportingSelectedUserGUID,
                    'timeId': reportingSelectedTimeGUID,
                    'hierarchyGroupId': reportingSelectedHierarchyGroupGUID,
                    'nodeId': reportingSelectedNodeGUID,
                    'memberId': reportingSelectedMemberGUID,
                    'fileName': fileName // Pass the filename to the controller
                },
                success: function (response, opts) {

                    Ext.DomHelper.append(Ext.getBody(), {
                        tag: 'iframe',
                        frameBorder: 0,
                        width: 0,
                        height: 0,
                        css: 'display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;',
                        src: '../Temp/' + fileName // Grab that same file that's created
                    });
                }
            })
        }
```

I also modified by server code to save the file to a temp folder on the server, to be retrieved by the client.